# If simple function attains a finite number of values, how can it estimate a function which attains an infinite number of values?

Tags: measure-theory

An amateur question here: I'm studying about measure theory and I've so far learned that a function $f$ is measurable if there exists a sequence of simple functions $s_n$ which converge into $f$, that is:

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n(x).$$

Now, I've learned from my study material that simple functions have a range which consists from a finite number of values. It seems somewhat confusing to me on how a simple function, which attains a finite number of values, can converge into a function with an infinite range? Say for example the function $f(x)=x^2$ on the interval $[0,2]$. The function $f$ attains infinite number of values on this interval so it's somewhat confusing on how simple functions with a range of finitely many values converges into this.

Can you help me clear up with this fundamental misunderstanding/confusion I have here, thank you!

Comment: You take a limit, though.  That makes a pretty big difference.

Comment: Think about it from the Riemann integral point of view.  There, you break up the **domain** into a finite number of pieces, use those as the base of your rectangles, using the function values as heights to get areas.  Wouldn't you argue that, *in the limit*, this makes sense to get the area under the curve, even though a single stage uses only finitely many pieces of data?  The Lebesgue integral is just the "turn your head 90 degrees" version of this.  Now we partition our **range** into finitely many values, take the measure of the preimages, and multiply to get the area.

Comment: Doesn't essentially the same issue arise with every finite-length decimal being able to "estimate" a real number which has infinitely many decimals? For example, $\pi$ can be "estimated" by $3.1,$ $3.14,$ $3.141,$ $3.1415,$ $3.14159, \ldots$

Comment: Thank you @Randall et al., I think I got it now. Indeed, thinking about the Riemann case made it more clear. The concept of infinity sometimes leads into strange places ;-) But I got it now. Thank you all! If you want to change your comment into an answer, I'd happily accept it. It also many times becomes obvious when you see it geometrically.

Comment: Drawing the $s_n$ helps. The idea is that for small $\varepsilon$, the function $s$ defined by $s(x) = n\varepsilon$ wherever $n\varepsilon \leq f(x) < (n + 1)\varepsilon$ approximates $f$ well. Then $s$ is truncated so that only finitley many $n$ are considered. You are left composing $f$ with functions $g_n \colon [0, \infty] \to \mathbb{R}$ that get closer and closer to $g(x) = x$.